# Why bokeh Label option render_mode='css' works on a systems but returns an error on a second one?

Tags: python, label, bokeh

I have the following piece of code to add a text box to my plot:

```
citation = bokeh.models.Label(x=xPosition, y=yPosition, x_units='screen', y_units='screen',
                 text=textstr, 
                 render_mode='css',
                 border_line_color='wheat', border_line_alpha=0,
                 background_fill_color='wheat', background_fill_alpha=0)

p.add_layout(citation)
```

The above piece of code runs flawlessly in one laptop while on a second one I get the following error.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[58], line 80
     74 p.line('distance', 'grade', name='Grade', color="blue", line_width=0.30, 
     75        y_range_name='Grade', line_dash="4 2", source=source)
     78 #labels = LabelSet(x='weight', y='height', text='names',
     79 #              x_offset=5, y_offset=5, source=source, render_mode='canvas')
---> 80 citation = bokeh.models.Label(x=xPosition, y=yPosition, x_units='screen', y_units='screen',
     81                  text=textstr, 
     82                  render_mode='css',
     83                  border_line_color='wheat', border_line_alpha=0,
     84                  background_fill_color='wheat', background_fill_alpha=0)
     86 p.add_layout(citation)
     89 # show the results

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\models\annotations\labels.py:122, in Label.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    121 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
--> 122     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\models\annotations\labels.py:78, in TextAnnotation.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     77 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
---> 78     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\models\annotations\annotation.py:49, in Annotation.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     48 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
---> 49     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\models\renderers\renderer.py:76, in Renderer.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     75 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
---> 76     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\model\model.py:110, in Model.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    107 if "id" in kwargs:
    108     raise ValueError("initializing 'id' is not allowed")
--> 110 super().__init__(**kwargs)
    111 default_theme.apply_to_model(self)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\core\has_props.py:298, in HasProps.__init__(self, **properties)
    296     if value is Undefined or value is Intrinsic:
    297         continue
--> 298     setattr(self, name, value)
    300 for name in self.properties() - set(properties.keys()):
    301     desc = self.lookup(name)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\core\has_props.py:333, in HasProps.__setattr__(self, name, value)
    330 if isinstance(descriptor, property): # Python property
    331     return super().__setattr__(name, value)
--> 333 self._raise_attribute_error_with_matches(name, properties)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\core\has_props.py:368, in HasProps._raise_attribute_error_with_matches(self, name, properties)
    365 if not matches:
    366     matches, text = sorted(properties), "possible"
--> 368 raise AttributeError(f"unexpected attribute {name!r} to {self.__class__.__name__}, {text} attributes are {nice_join(matches)}")

AttributeError: unexpected attribute 'render_mode' to Label, possible attributes are angle, angle_units, background_fill_alpha, background_fill_color, border_line_alpha, border_line_cap, border_line_color, border_line_dash, border_line_dash_offset, border_line_join, border_line_width, coordinates, group, js_event_callbacks, js_property_callbacks, level, name, propagate_hover, subscribed_events, syncable, tags, text, text_align, text_alpha, text_baseline, text_color, text_font, text_font_size, text_font_style, text_line_height, text_outline_color, visible, x, x_offset, x_range_name, x_units, y, y_offset, y_range_name or y_units
```

Could anybody, please, help me in trying to solve the problem?

Note: If I comment out the render_mode='css', line the code works fine in the second system but border lines are not displayed.

Both systems are running windows 10 and bokeh is upgraded to the last available version.

Thanks.
Paolo.

Comment: What version of bokeh are you using

Comment: bokeh    Version: 3.1.1   Build: py39h9909e9c_0

Comment: `render_mode` is deprecated in bokeh 3, so downgrade the library and it should work

Comment: Downgraded to bokeh version 2.4.3 but the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in bokeh 3.x is to remove the `render_mode` and set the alpha value to a number different from 0 (this is invisible).

```
from bokeh.models import Label
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

p = figure(width=300, height=250)
p.line([1,2,3],[0,1,2])
citation = Label(
    x=1, y=1, x_units='screen', y_units='screen',
    text='Text',
    border_line_color='wheat',
    background_fill_color='wheat'
)
p.add_layout(citation)
show(p)
```

[image: s]